# Delete Local Administrator

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, scripting

Back story real quick: some reason some servers have 2 local admin account... no idea, I took over the job and cleaning everything up.

I need to go through 600-ish (or more) servers to delete the extra account.

PowerShell is great but can't work this out. How can I modify and read this location in PowerShell?

I can read up to here: HKLM:\SAM, and cannot see HKLM:\SAM\SAM... ? How can I get PowerShell to edit permissions and read this location?

Once I can see this location I will work out how to delete it remove-item-somethingsomething

Thanks all :)

Comment: You shouldn't attempt to manipulate accounts using the registry.  But there is a command line tool, `net user` that has a `/delete` option.  (And there's probably a Powershell equivalent too.)

Comment: this wont delete a "built-in" account, this is the first thing i tried, thanks :)

Comment: You can't delete a built-in account, full stop.  But there's only one built-in local administrator account, the other one must be a normal account, which you should be able to delete in the usual way.  What are the SIDs for the two accounts?  (The `whoami /all` command will show this.)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to:

- first get a list of all LocalAdmin accounts,
- without the builtin Administrator whose SID ends with -500,
- use the following (untested) script which uses a wildcard for the possibly localized group name
  (i.e. Administratoren in German)

---

```
## Q:\Test\2019\04\08\SO_961951.ps1

$scriptBlock = { Get-LocalGroup Admin* |
                  Get-LocalGroupMember | 
                   Where SID -notmatch '-500$' | 
                    Select-Object * }

$Servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'OperatingSystem -like "*windows*server*"' |
    Select-Object Name,OperatingSystem

$LocalAdmins = foreach($Server in $Servers){
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server.Name -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
}

$LocalAdmins | Export-Csv .\LocalAdmins.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Sample output:

```
Name              SID                                            PrincipalSource ObjectClass
----              ---                                            --------------- -----------
Server\LotPings   S-1-5-21-1234567890-987654321-1234567890-1001            Local Benutzer
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use script like this if you have correct access to remote servers:

```
$scriptBlock = 
{
Remove-LocalUser -Name UserToDelete
}
Invoke-Command -ComputerName RemoteServerName -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```

Comment: Will this delete the 'built-in' local administrator account ? I will test it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This was my way of doing it.

```
&"\\ServerExes\PavlesFolder\PsExec64.exe" \\$Computer -accepteula -nobanner -i -s cmd /c "echo . | powershell.exe (Remove-Item HKLM:\SAM\SAM\Domains\Account\Users\Names\$account -Force)"
```

it must be ran as 'SYSTEM' so I'm using PsExec.
When it deletes from registry the account still shows up in compmgmt.msc, so to work around that, I re-create the user and delete again (using ADSI).. and its gone.

messy, but works...

function created to do the work:

```
Function Delete-Account-AsSystem {

    Param (
        [string]$Computer,
        [string]$Account
    )

    &"\\ServerExes\PavlesFolder\PsExec64.exe" \\$Computer -accepteula -nobanner -i -s cmd /c "echo . | powershell.exe (Remove-Item HKLM:\SAM\SAM\Domains\Account\Users\Names\$Account -Force)"

    If($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0){

        If(Get-WmiObject -Class win32_UserAccount -Filter "LocalAccount=True" -ComputerName $Computer | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Admin"} -eq $null){

            $temppassword = "P@ssword1!"
            $objOu = [ADSI]”WinNT://$Computer“

            $objUser = $objOU.Create("User", $Account)
            $objUser.SetPassword($temppassword)
            $objUser.SetInfo()

            $objOuDelete = [ADSI]”WinNT://$Computer“
            $objOuDelete.Delete("User",$Account)

            Write-Output "Deleted account."

        }#end if

    }Else{

        Write-Output "Didnt delete account."

    }#end if


}#end function


Delete-Account-AsSystem -Computer server01 -Account Admin
```